# several items act when click on a RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a list by using `RecycleView`. I want when clicking on one of the items, that item acts. But in addition to that item, several other items also act.
I have used `setOnClickListener` in `onBindViewHolder`.

How can I solve this problem?

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.viewholder> {


private List<MyListModel> myListModels;
Context context;

public adapter(List<MyListModel> myListModels, Context context)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.myListModels = myListModels;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public adapter.viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    return new viewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final adapter.viewholder holder, int position) {
    MyListModel myListModel = myListModels.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(myListModel.getName());

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            holder.relativeLayout.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(700).start();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myListModels.size();
}

class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    TextView name;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    CardView cardView;

    public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_list_name);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_list_cardview);
        relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_list_relativeLayout);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity Class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<MyListModel> myListModel = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
    myListModel.add(new MyListModel("item "+i));


    RecyclerView recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.Recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter Adapter = new adapter(myListModel,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);

}}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfURp.gif)

Comment: do not put onClick listener on `onBindViewHolder` as it will set it to every value that is being binded, memory usage will spike everytime you scroll and your app will lag if there is large amount of data, so instead set the click listener on your `viewholder` on any view you want  and use an interface to pass values if you need to.

Comment: follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0

Comment: As Pemba mentioned , its bad practice to  have your click listener in onBindViewHolder . 
Instead have your clickListener in viewHolder , and animate your item relative your itemPosition .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecyclerView reuse views. That's why this problem occurs.

Add `boolean b` variable in `MyListModel` class & set true when you click &  set this code inside `OnBindViewHolder`

```
if(!b)
holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
else holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```